How to Convert Styled-Components CSSObject into Inline Style Tag without React Context?
I am working on a Next.js project, and I need to convert a styled-components CSSObject into an inline  tag. However, I do not want to use any React context for this purpose.
I tried the following code:

import { css } from 'styled-components';

css({});

But I encountered the following error:
Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component
It appears that the styled-components library relies on a context that only functions in client components, but I am aiming for a server-side approach or any other method that doesn't involve React context.

How can I convert a styled-components CSSObject into an inline  tag without using any React context?

As error suggesting you need to make this component client side render because styled-component relies on context.
Add 'use client' on top of file to get rid of error.

Thanks @mabbas! When I do it, I have a flash where the CSS is not applied. After a few ms the page is displayed correctly. Do you know how to improve this?

@Charles
Try to render the whole page on the client side. This issue might be due to a mix of server-side and client-side rendering, though I'm not entirely sure. The best approach would be to review the code and debug the issue.
